# CSS matching attribute value with another

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible with CSS to match based on the value of another attribute?
For example:

```
<div data-attr1="abc" data-attr2="def"></div>
<div data-attr1="abc" data-attr2="abc"></div>
```

I would want something like this (which does not work):

```
div[data-attr1=data-attr2]
```

Which would ideally return the second DIV, but not the first.

Comment: Basically..."NO". you'd need Javascript. CSS doesn't do *if statements*, which is what you are asking for.

Comment: That's what I thought. But a man can dream, can't he?

Comment: @AaronJSpetner: Absolutely (re "can dream"), CSS has a lot more now than it did back in CSS 2.1. :-) But no, this isn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, CSS doesn't have that. You'll need to use JavaScript instead, or have whatever's producing the HTML add a class or marker attribute when those other two attributes match.

[Here's the latest selectors specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/); the section would be [attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors), but there isn't anything like that there.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with CSS. With JavaScript (jQuery) you can do this:

```
var dataAttr = new Array();
$.each($("[data-attr1]"), function(i, el){
    if($(el).attr("data-attr1") == $(el).attr("data-attr2")){
        dataAttr.push(el);
    }
});

console.log($(dataAttr));
```

Where `dataAttr` will contain `<div data-attr1="abc" data-attr2="abc"></div>` and any other div whose `data-attr1` is equal to its `data-attr2`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery:

```
if ($('div').attr('data-attr1') == $('div').attr('data-attr2'))
```

Comment: The question was about CSS, not JavaScript.